# How to create an arraylist of all email addresses in an Active Directory OU in an asp.net c# web forms application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have read several posts, but I haven't been able to get anything to work for me. I would like to create an arraylist of all display names within the "Standard Users" OU. I will then use that arraylist to populate a dropdown list. I found the following in another thread, but it provides groups and not users within the specified OU:

```
public ArrayList Groups()
{
    ArrayList groups = new ArrayList();
    foreach (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference group in
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups)
    {
        groups.Add(group.Translate(typeof
            (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString());
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Can this be modified to provide the list of users in the Standard Users OU? Or should I use a different approach?

I also found this, but I get an error (red lines under 'std_users') stating 'not all code paths return a value'.

```
public ArrayList std_users()
{
    // List of strings for your names
    List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();

    // create your domain context and define the OU container to search in
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myco.org", "OU=Standard Users, dc=myco, dc=org");

    // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal (user)
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

    // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

    // find all matches
    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
    {
        // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
        allUsers.Add(found.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using c#, Visual Studio 2013 and the framework is 4.5.1.

Comment: 'not all code paths return a value' because the `std_users` function never returns anything.

Comment: Stop using `ArrayList`! This was dead with .NET 2.0 - it's about time to switch to  `List<string>` or more generally `List<T>` .....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `return allUsers;` to `std_users()` and let us know if that works for you.

Comment: the error is now gone, but I get a new error on the "return allUsers".  It states "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList'".  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: change `public ArrayList std_users()` to `public List<string> std_users()`

Comment: thank you for the help.  I get a new error now, when I attempt to use both of your solutions.  I get an error stating that "there is no such object on the server" in regards to the qbeUser.  The error is related to the following line: 'PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);'.

Comment: Please disregard the last question - it works as posted by dbagley.  marc_s post also works.  I have now quit using ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

First off: **STOP USING** `ArrayList` - that type is **dead** since .NET 2.0 and should not be used - use `List<string>` (or more generally: `List<T>`) instead - much better for performance and usability!

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
public List<string> GetAllEmailsFromUsersContainer()
{
    List<string> users = new List<string>();

    // create your domain context and bind to the standard CN=Users
    // container to get all "standard" users
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, "CN=Users,dc=YourCompany,dc=com"))
    {
        // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
        // which is not locked out, and has an e-mail address   
        UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
        qbeUser.IsAccountLockedOut = false;
        qbeUser.EmailAddress = "*";

        // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
        PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

        // find all matches
        foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
        {
            users.Add(found.EmailAddress);
        }
    }

    return users;
}
```